# I can't set Xubuntu 13.04 to connect to the nearest access point

Tags: wireless, networking, xubuntu

At my house there are 3 wireless connections and they are all joined together to make one.

I want to connect to my nearest one, but it connects to another one. This happens often, but after a day its gone and then the next day it comes back again.

Does anyone have solution?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I am using Ubuntu, but I am pretty sure there must be something very similar to this on xubuntu:

Edit Network Connections -> choose the connection you do not want to connect to, click edit -> under the tab "General" uncheck the box "automatically connect to this network when it is available"

Repeat those steps for all connections you do not want your system to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the top right corner of the screen and click on network manager>edit connection>wireless then enter the mac address of the one you want to connect too.